# jQuery Autocomplete wrong item in text box on select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, jquery

When a user begins typing in the `DRMCompanyName` input text box, and autocomplete feature fires that displays both the company name and the company id. When the use clicks on a selection, the company name and id are to be placed into the `DRMCompanyName` text box and the id in the `DRMCompanyId` text box just below.

When the `json` results are returned from the controller, the code in the autocomplete ajax `success` function populates the drop down list by setting the `label` to be equal to the `value` (company name) plus the `key` (company id) being returned. Likewise the `value` is set to just the `key` (company id).

When the user selects a particular item, the `label` is supposed to go in the `DRMCompanyName` text box and the `value` in the `DRMCompanyId`. However, what winds up happening is the `value` gets placed in both.

I've scoured my code over and over and cannot find out why the `label` does not get placed in the `DRMCompanyName` field.

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('#DRMCompanyName').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("compSearchByName", "AgentTransmission")',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: request,
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                        return {
                            label: value + " " + key,
                            value: key
                        };
                    }));
                },
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(ui);
            $('#DRMCompanyName').val(ui.item.label);
            $('#DRMCompanyName').text(ui.item.label);

            if ($('#DRMCompanyId').text() == '') {
                $('#DRMCompanyId').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#DRMCompanyId').text(ui.item.value);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a sample screen shot of the `ui` item from the `select` function above (the company name is blacked out for privacy). When I click on this particular item in the autocomplete drop down, `200014` gets placed in both the `DRMCompanyName` and `DRMCompanyId` fields.

[image]

**Razor Markup**

```
    <div class="M-editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DRMCompanyName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DRMCompanyName)
    </div>    

    <div class="M-editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DRMCompanyId)
    </div>
    <div class="M-editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DRMCompanyId, new { maxlength = 10, title = "Start typing company name to activate DRM Company Name lookup. When DRM Company is found, select to fill in DRM Company ID and DRM Company Name fields." })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DRMCompanyId)
    </div>
```

**EDIT**

After following the suggestion in the answer below, I modified the `select` function like so:

```
        select: function (event, ui) {
            console.log(tempResults[ui.item.value]);
            $('#DRMCompanyName').val(tempResults[ui.item.value]);
            $('#DRMCompanyName').text(tempResults[ui.item.value]);

            if ($('#DRMCompanyId').text() == '') {
                $('#DRMCompanyId').val(ui.item.value);
                $('#DRMCompanyId').text(ui.item.value);
            }
        }
```

Based on the `console.log` readout, this accesses the correct value when the user clicks on the autocomplete item. However, it still places the value in both text boxes. What I can't understand, when I select `Inspect Element`, is that the correct value for `DRMCompanyName` actually is placed in the HTML, however it does not appear on the screen, only the `id` or `value` (as opposed to `label`).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `label: value + " " + key` which will of course add the id in the label.

When you set `$('#DRMCompanyName').val(ui.item.label);`, it's going to set what you concatenated in the `$.map` to the value.

One way to do this is to store a temporary result set from the data in the source ajax call to access later. With this temp set, you can now pull any object or key/value from it for use later.

**When getting results, store a temporary list of the results.**

```
var tempResults = [];

...
source: function (request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("compSearchByName", "AgentTransmission")',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: request,
        success: function (data) {
            tempResults = data;

            response($.map(data, function (value, key) {
                return {
                    label: value + " " + key,
                    value: key
                };
            }));
        },
    });
}
```

**Then, on the select, you can now access the stored data and set values:**

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = tempResults[ui.item.value].value;
    var id = tempResults[ui.item.value].key;

    $('#DRMCompanyName').val(name);
    $('#DRMCompanyName').text(name);

    if ($('#DRMCompanyId').text() == '') {
        $('#DRMCompanyId').val(id);
        $('#DRMCompanyId').text(id);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Forgetting one minor thing! Add this to the beginning of the `select:` function!

```
event.preventDefault();
```

By default, when selecting, the autocomplete will use the `ui.item.value` to populate the element that it's wired up with. Using `event.preventDefault()` will prevent the already wired up event handler to be called used within the autocomplete.

[event.preventDefault() documentation.](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Comment: No, that's what we want according to our users. The issue is that the concatenated `label` of  `value + " " + key` isn't showing up in the proper field. Instead the `value` is being placed in both.

Comment: Are you missing the second part of your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately this still winds up putting the id in the `DRMCompanyName` field for some reason. Good idea tho

Comment: Nevermind, this appears to be working but will not display properly (see edits if you're still interested). Thx!

Comment: Any chance you could add a brief explanation to your answer as well?

Comment: I've added some explanations in there.